# For loop not working correctly with jQuery axois function

Tags: laravel

I am trying to show product using axois function , i have no idea how can i get data in axois by using for loop Does anyone have an idea  please help me thanks.

please check response in console. https://ibb.co/YhqMsYZ

**controller**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $products = Product::with('productColorGallary')->where('status', 1)->get();


        $data = [

            'product' => $products


        ];

        return response()->json($data, 200);
    }
```

**jquery script**

```
let url = "{{route('products.store')}}";
axios.get(url, {
params:{
}
}).then((res)=>{
let product =res.data;
//  console.log(product);
for(var i =0; i< product.length; i++)
 {
   $('#product').append(
  `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
<div class="wallprodCard">
  <div class="prodcardImage">
    <img src="{{url('')}}/assets/images/wallpapers/wallpaper-1-01.jpg" alt="">
    <a class="prodcardFancy" href="{{url('')}}/assets/images/wallpapers/wallpaper-1-01.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Flooring">
      <i class="fa fa-search-plus">
      </i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="prodcardDescp">
    <a href="{{url('')}}/wallpaper-details">
      <h4 class="prodcardtitle">product name
      </h4>
    </a>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
`);
}
    });
  });
```

**html view**

```
  <div class="tab-content">
        <div  class="tab tab-active" data-id="tab1">
          <div class="row">
            <div id="product"> </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!--end of tab one-->
      </div>
```

Comment: what u r getting on ` console.log(product);` can u post that as well

Comment: use `let product =res.data.product;` this is issue i can see

Comment: please check  https://ibb.co/r5g45wL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as `res.data` this is not product array
use  this

```js
let product =res.data.product;
```

as ur loop in javascript and  and u r using ``` `` ``` this operator so u can use

`string text ${expression} string text`   ref link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

---

```js
 $('#product').append(
  `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
<div class="wallprodCard">
  <div class="prodcardImage">
    <img src="{{url('')}}/assets/images/wallpapers/wallpaper-1-01.jpg" alt="">
    <a class="prodcardFancy" href="{{url('')}}/assets/images/wallpapers/wallpaper-1-01.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Flooring">
      <i class="fa fa-search-plus">
      </i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="prodcardDescp">
    <a href="{{url('')}}/wallpaper-details">
      <h4 class="prodcardtitle">product name
      </h4>
    </a>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
${dynamicdata} // here u can use your javascript variable
`);
```

Comment: ok sir please check for loop and guide me how can i get data in html using loop ?

Comment: i have no idea how can i get data by using loop in axois function ?

Answer (score 0):

i find this useful and it will be worth trying it. in your component, you can initialize an empty array in the data() methods. assume you use an array called *products*,then this is how your script tag should be

```js
<script>
export default{
    data(){
    return{
    //now the empty array
    products:[]
    }
    },
    methods:{
    getProducts:function(){
    axios.get(url).then((response)=>{
    this.products=response.data
    //this saves the json data in the array
    //you can then catch the error
    //then check the html above
    })
    }
    },
    created(){
    this.getProducts()
    //
    }
}
</script>
```

```html
<div class="row">
<!-- the loop will create n numbers of elements with a col-sm-4 class for all length of products-->
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-6 col-6" v-for="product in products" :key="product.id">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-6">
<div class="wallprodCard">
  <div class="prodcardImage">
    <img :src="assets/images/wallpapers/wallpaper-1-01.jpg" alt="">
    <a class="prodcardFancy" href="assets/images/wallpapers/wallpaper-1-01.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-caption="Flooring">
      <i class="fa fa-search-plus">
      </i>
    </a><!--Kindly Note thatif this field is dynamic, you mightwant to bind the href attribute to the dynamic value ie. the a href should be a :href="dynamic value"-->
  </div>
  <div class="prodcardDescp">
    <a href="/wallpaper-details"><!--Kindly Note thatif this field is dynamic, you mightwant to bind the href attribute to the dynamic value ie. the a href should be a :href="dynamic value"-->
      <h4 class="prodcardtitle">product name
      </h4>
    </a>
    <p class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```